# Block on Adminhtml dissappear after upgrade to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, adminhtml

This is my code:

on app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/infocurci/fidelity.xml

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_info">
        <block type="infocurci_fidelity/adminhtml_riepilogocliente" name="infocurci_fidelity_riepilogocliente" template="infocurci/fidelity/riepilogocliente.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

on Magento 1.5, it works fine.
After upgrade to Magento 1.9, my block is not show yet.
If I try:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="infocurci_fidelity/adminhtml_riepilogocliente" name="infocurci_fidelity_riepilogocliente" template="infocurci/fidelity/riepilogocliente.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

it works fine, it appears on the end of page. But I want this code at the end of "order_info" block..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this layout was in **1.5**, but... have you tried that with `after="-"` parameter?

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_info">
        <block type="infocurci_fidelity/adminhtml_riepilogocliente" name="infocurci_fidelity_riepilogocliente" template="infocurci/fidelity/riepilogocliente.phtml" after="-"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```